# xcode debugging goes back and forth during stepping through the code

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging

I have a really weird problem with Xcode 3.2.5

In a normal code sequence XCode steps couple of lines back then continues, then again sometimes back and continues again during step mode.

This only happens in one project, but there in all files. Here an example:

When jumping in this function Xcode goes through the lines in the following sequence:
2 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 ->5 -> 8 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 ->...

I dont understand what is going on here. Please do you have any idea?

Rebooting the machine and the iPhone doesn't help.

By the way, the complete code works fine and runs without errors. It seems that the cursor sometimes goes to lines where the code is not being executed. If a certain line is entered twice by the cursor, only the second time it changes the variables in assignments etc..

Really weird!

Thanks for any hint...

```
 1  - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 // D_IN;
 2  [super viewWillAppear:animated];


 //get the dataManager global Object, so we always have a structured accesss to the data!
3 WebiAppDelegate *mainDelegate = (WebiAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
4 self.webiDataManager = mainDelegate.webiDataManager;

5 message.hidden = YES;
6 message.text = @"";
7 message.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
...
```

Comment: Are you trying to debug optimized code, by any chance?

Comment: Is the compiler optimizing your code? If it is, it could be performing operations relating to those lines without changing the variable, then going to a different line, and coming back to finish.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I agree with the comments.  It looks like you're trying to debug optimized code.  Try compiling with no optimization and the debugger should behave more sensibly.

e.g. `gcc -O0 ...`

Comment: oh yes - thanks to your comments I found that the project is still in distribution mode - I have to set everything back to developer mode.